# Page visibility API: sometimes on android - chrome the event is not fired after 10-20 minute that the browser is in background

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am testing Page visibility API and on Android with Chrome browser very often if I resume the browser from background open at the page with the code at the bottom the visible event is not fired.  It still indicates hidden.
This can happen when the browser is in background for about 15 or more minutes.

Someone can tell me why this happen?

Chrome is at version 80.
Android I am using for testing is version 8.
I tested it on another smartphone with a recent version of android and it seems to work better, but this doesn't depends just on Chrome version?  it is up to date on both.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: tested with other devices and it's the same. There are cases where it doesn't fire the event when the browser it's bring to front from background.

Page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <h1 id="test">Test</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Script code, modified from the demo at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

```
// Set the name of the hidden property and the change event for visibility
var hidden, visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
    hidden = "hidden";
    visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "msHidden";
    visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "webkitHidden";
    visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    var d = new Date,
        dformat = [d.getMonth() + 1,
            d.getDate(),
            d.getFullYear()
        ].join('/') + ' ' + [d.getHours(),
            d.getMinutes(),
            d.getSeconds()
        ].join(':');
    if (document[hidden]) {
        console.log("hidden");
        test.innerHTML = "HIDDEN - " + d;
    } else {
        console.log("visible");
        test.innerHTML = "VISIBLE - " + d;
    }
}

// Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || hidden === undefined) {
    console.log("This demo requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
} else {
    // Handle page visibility change
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
}
```

Comment: Is it work on switch tabs ? Problems is sometimes on lock unlock i guest....